# I can't find method name from this object in React

Tags: reactjs

In this example, `this` object is in the `App` scope, so I thought If I try `console.log(this)` then I will find `recall` and `changeMyName` function from `this` object.

but there isn't any method name in `this` object, I'm a little confused because `this.changeMyName` means I can access `changeMyName` function from `this` object.

Where can I find method names in `this` object?

```js
// example code
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component{
  changeMyName() {
    console.log(this)
    this.recall();
  }

  recall() {
    console.log('recall');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <button onClick={this.changeMyName.bind(this)}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
// result of console.log(this)
App {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, _reactInternals: FiberNode…}
props: Object
context: Object
refs: Object
updater: Object
isMounted: ƒ isMounted() {}
enqueueSetState: ƒ enqueueSetState() {}
enqueueReplaceState: ƒ enqueueReplaceState() {}
enqueueForceUpdate: ƒ enqueueForceUpdate() {}
_reactInternals: FiberNode
_reactInternalInstance: Object
state: null
isReactComponent: Object
setState: ƒ () {}
<constructor>: "Function"
forceUpdate: ƒ () {}
<constructor>: "Function"
<constructor>: "App"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `changeMyName`, `recall`, and `render` functions are made available through inheritence. They aren't on the object itself, but on the prototype of the object. When you access `this.changeMyName`, javascript behind the scenes checks `this`, doesn't see a `changeMyName` property, so then it checks the prototype of `this` and finds it there. The prototype of an instance of a class can be accessed via Object.getPrototypeOf, or the deprecated `__proto__` property.

An additional complication is that `class` sets all methods to be [non-enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). So they won't show up on things like Object.keys, and won't be logged by console.log. So we'll need to use Object.getOwnPropertyNames to get the keys

```js
class Example {
  hello() {
    console.log('hello world');
  }
}

const e = new Example();
console.log(e);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e));
console.log(e.__proto__);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e.__proto__));
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(e));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(e)));
```